# Find two biggest values for one key in a multimap

Tags: c++, key, multimap, std-pair

I have a multimap consisting of a key that is a pair of ints and the values of the keys are float numbers.
Now I want to have the 2 biggest values for all my keys.
In my example the Key (1, 1) should result in Value 5.8 and 3.7.
Key (2, 2) should result in 2.4 and 1.5.
**To point it out:** I don't know the number and appearance of my keys. So I don't know if key (2, 2) exists.

Here is the code:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // Create some values - both vectors have the same size
    // The pairs and the thetas may be unsorted
    vector<pair<int, int>> pairs;
    pairs.push_back(make_pair(1, 1));
    pairs.push_back(make_pair(1, 1));
    pairs.push_back(make_pair(1, 1));
    pairs.push_back(make_pair(2, 2));
    pairs.push_back(make_pair(2, 2));
    pairs.push_back(make_pair(3, 3));
    pairs.push_back(make_pair(3, 3));
    pairs.push_back(make_pair(1, 1));

    vector<float> theta;
    theta.push_back(1.4);
    theta.push_back(2.4);
    theta.push_back(3.7);
    theta.push_back(2.4);
    theta.push_back(1.5);
    theta.push_back(1.6);
    theta.push_back(2.4);
    theta.push_back(5.8);

    multimap<pair<int, int>, float> similarities;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < pairs.size(); i++) {
        similarities.insert(make_pair(make_pair(pairs[i].first, pairs[i].second), theta[i]));
    }

}
```

In my specific case I don't know which key pairs are defined in my multimap.
I think also that perhaps multimap is not the right choice but I am not sure what's a better type.
I have tried to keep the vector format of theta but then it is hard to keep track of the related pairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope that I got you right:

```
auto range = similarities.equal_range(make_pair(1,1));

size_t found = 0; float highest, second_highest;

if (range.first != similarities.end() && range.first != range.second) {
  ++found;
  highest = (*std::max_element(range.first++, range.second)).second;
  if (range.first != range.second) {
    ++found;
    second_highest =
      (*std::max_element(range.first++, range.second, [&](auto a, auto b){ return a.second < b.second && b.second < highest; })).second;
  }
}

if (found > 0)
  std::cout << highest<< std::endl;
if (found > 1)
  std::cout << second_highest << std::endl;
```

The above would not give you the same value twice though.

Comment: That is what I meant but what could I do if I don't know the keys? Key 1,1 may exist but key 2, 1 does not. So I cannot use `equal_range` right?

Comment: That's why i put in the work so that it does. Try the code with a key that doesn't exist. Why did you think i put in the checks and the found variable and the specialised predicate in the second `max_element`?

Comment: Would be great if you'd accept the answer? That'd be awesome.

Comment: Leaves some time to enjoy your Grillteller. You might have to tweak the predicate to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options here.

- Keep the existing `multimap` and just do a linear search over the values to find the two largest.
- Use `map<pair<int, int>, set<float, std::greater<float> > >` instead, and then the first two items are immediately accessible once you look up the key.
- Use `map<pair<int, int>, vector<float> >` and keep the vector sorted on insertion. Better when doing more lookups than inserts.
- Use `map<pair<int, int>, vector<float> >` and `partial_sort` the first two items when needing to retrieve the highest two values. Better when doing more inserts than lookups.